# visualise summary statistics in R

Tags: r

How can I create pie chart and bar graph in R from this summary of data:

```
gender        race.ethnicity    parental.level.of.education
female:518    group A: 89       associate's degree:222  
male  :482    group B:190       bachelor's degree :118  
              group C:319       high school       :196 
              group D:262       master's degree   : 59
              group E:140       some college      :226  
                                some high school  :179
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gender <- c(518, 482)
names(gender) <- c("male", "female")
pie(gender, names(gender))
barplot(gender)
```

Same for your other categories, e.g.

```
groups <- c(89, 190, 319, 262, 140)
names(groups) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
pie(groups, names(groups))
barplot(groups)
```

returns:

[image]